# IIS host computer vs network computer 403 forbidden

Tags: firefox

I have an unusual problem with my web app. 
The web application runs nicely on the host computer with no problems.

The problem comes in when a network computer access the web app. Here the website will load and work properly. But when the user tries to refresh (Ctrl+R or F5 or Ctrl+SHift+R[refresh cache]) the page, he gets several 403 forbidden access errors for JS/CSS/image files but he wont get any 403 forbidden access errors when he follow s(clicks) the link to the page.

The web app is set up with IIS on Windows XP, with PHP 5 and MYSQL 5.5.  I have tried with several different computers and have recreated the problem in all of them. The browser is FF 9.0.1 on all the computers and all are Windows XP.

Comment: Check website log -- what error subcode is generated for such problematic request (main error code = 403, next "column" in the log should be error subcode (0, 1, 2 etc). What I think right now -- maybe you are hitting number of simultaneous requests and IIS thinks that you may be DOS-ing it ...

Comment: @LazyOne could this happen if there is a memory leak? Since, I have updated some of the code, the problem has disappeared. the major changes in the code were from optimization of SQL queries.